# SoundWire streaming but no sound

Tags: android, pulseaudio

I installed SoundWire client + server. The server communicates with the client sending evenly sized packets every few milliseconds.

The server's status goes to green "Connected". The connect button on the client turns from white to orange.

All in all this looks as if sound is being sent, but no audio.

Volume control shows a nice jumping VU-meter in the Output Devices Tab.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the volume control settings.

The Recording Tab should also show a jumping VU-meter. If not: Change the 'Alsa capture from'